# how to store TxnLineID while getting sales receipt add response?

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I want to store `TxnLineID` of each line item which comes in the response to adding sales receipt into quickbook desktop using qbxml, in my database but the `TxnLineID` are multiple lines which come in XML format response.

so how can I update it in my MySQL query?

also, I came to know that each TxnLineID is required while updating

**i.e** SalesReceiptModRq. so I want to store it in my database

below is the response came from sales receipt add procedure

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<SalesReceiptAddRs requestID="406" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
<SalesReceiptRet>
<TxnID>1D7-1574079359</TxnID>
<TimeCreated>2019-11-18T17:45:59+05:30</TimeCreated>
<TimeModified>2019-11-18T17:45:59+05:30</TimeModified>
<EditSequence>1574079359</EditSequence>
<TxnNumber>93</TxnNumber>
<CustomerRef>
<ListID>8000002F-1573831264</ListID>
<FullName>giri rawal</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<TemplateRef>
<ListID>80000009-1573129982</ListID>
<FullName>Custom Sales Receipt</FullName>
</TemplateRef>
<TxnDate>2019-11-14</TxnDate>
<RefNumber>42</RefNumber>
<BillAddress>
<Addr1>Keith Palmer Jr.</Addr1>
<Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
<City>Storrs-Mansfield</City>
<State>CT</State>
<PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
<Country>USA</Country>
</BillAddress>
<BillAddressBlock>
<Addr1>Keith Palmer Jr.</Addr1>
<Addr3>134 Stonemill Road</Addr3>
<Addr4>Storrs-Mansfield, CT 06268</Addr4>
<Addr5>United States</Addr5>
</BillAddressBlock>
<IsPending>false</IsPending>
<DueDate>2019-11-14</DueDate>
<ShipDate>2019-11-14</ShipDate>
<Subtotal>50.00</Subtotal>
<ItemSalesTaxRef>
<ListID>8000002A-1573055104</ListID>
<FullName>sales tax</FullName>
</ItemSalesTaxRef>
<SalesTaxPercentage>5.00</SalesTaxPercentage>
<SalesTaxTotal>2.50</SalesTaxTotal>
<TotalAmount>52.50</TotalAmount>
<IsToBePrinted>true</IsToBePrinted>
<IsToBeEmailed>false</IsToBeEmailed>
<CustomerSalesTaxCodeRef>
<ListID>80000001-1572867591</ListID>
<FullName>Tax</FullName>
</CustomerSalesTaxCodeRef>
<DepositToAccountRef>
<ListID>80000026-1573129983</ListID>
<FullName>Undeposited Funds</FullName>
</DepositToAccountRef>
<SalesReceiptLineRet>
<TxnLineID>1D9-1574079359</TxnLineID>
<ItemRef>
<ListID>80000030-1573662395</ListID>
<FullName>test</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<Desc>The Hitchhiker&apos;s Guide to the Galaxy</Desc>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Rate>25.00</Rate>
<Amount>25.00</Amount>
<SalesTaxCodeRef>
<ListID>80000001-1572867591</ListID>
<FullName>Tax</FullName>
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
</SalesReceiptLineRet>
<SalesReceiptLineRet>
<TxnLineID>1DA-1574079359</TxnLineID>
<ItemRef>
<ListID>80000030-1573662395</ListID>
<FullName>test</FullName>
</ItemRef>
<Desc>The Hitchhiker&apos;s Guide to the Galaxy</Desc>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Rate>25.00</Rate>
<Amount>25.00</Amount>
<SalesTaxCodeRef>
<ListID>80000001-1572867591</ListID>
<FullName>Tax</FullName>
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
</SalesReceiptLineRet>
</SalesReceiptRet>
</SalesReceiptAddRs>
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE sale_invoice_details SET quickbooks_txnLineId = '" .$idents['TxnLineID']. "'  WHERE sale_invoice_id = " . (int) $ID);
```

this is my query. but how to loop `$idents['TxnLineID']`? for multiple line items?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This looks like simple XML parsing - have you done a Google search for how to parse XML with PHP?

Comment: i managed to add ,edit ,update products, customers and sales recipt in quickbooks pro 2020 with the help of web connector. stuck on this point

Comment: Great! Post your code so we can see what you've tried so far, and we'll be able to help.

Comment: i have solved the problem myself. anyways thanks for your response guys!!!!!!!!!